# Prove that $\{ f(x_n) \}$ converges if $f$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to prove the following theorem:

> Suppose $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ and that $c$ is a cluster point of $S$.
> Let $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Then $\exists$ a
> sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n \in S \backslash \{c\}$ such that
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = c$ and $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges.

I know that if $c$ is a cluster point of $S$, then there is a sequence $\{ x_n \}$ of elements in $S \backslash \{ c \}$ that converges to $c$. But I'm not sure how to show then that $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges.

So far I know that if $f$ is bounded, then $\exists B\geq 0$ such that $\forall x \in S$, $|f(x)|\leq B$.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I don’t think this is true. You can consider the indicator function of $[0,1)$ defined on the interval S = $[0,1]$. Then, $1$ is a cluster point of S, but for any sequence converging to $1$, the value of the function is 1, but the function at $1$ is $0$.

Comment: A bounded sequence of real numbers has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @algebroo: it is not being asked that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(c)$. Indeed, $c$ needn't even be in $S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $c$ is a cluster point, there exists a sequence $\{y_k\} \subset S\backslash \{c\}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty}y_k = c$.  Now apply the [Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) to the the bounded real number sequence $\{f(y_k)\}$, it follows that there exists a subsequence $\{f(y_{k_n})\}$ that converges. Take $x_n = y_{k_n}$ finishes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a subset of $[-B,B]$ and since any closed and bounded interval of $\Bbb R$ is compact, then every sequence defined on it (including $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$) has a convergent subsequence. Finishing the proof is easy, by refining $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ to those subsequence terms.